# Easiest way to launch a MAUI app exe on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, maui

Is there a way to run the exe on a Windows desktop without doing the installer and deployment steps? I noticed everything needed ends up in the AppX folder under bin\debug\win10-x64 but because of the App Store integration it seems like it can only be launched via the start menu shortcut. Is there a way to manually create the shortcut? I'm in a dev/qa environment where we share & pass utilities around and it's kind of a pain to run an installer every time.

I'm down for making a simple reg script, if that's what it takes.
It looks like a reference is added in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\Deployment\Package\*`

And the details appear to be setup here:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\StateRepository\Cache\Application\Data\`

Comment: it's just a UWP app - look at the docs on UWP deployment options

Comment: I haven't had any luck with that, I can get it to begin the launch process but it then fails (using the protocol approach).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps

Comment: This works, but not without running the deployment step first...
https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/open-uwp-apps-from-command-line-windows-10/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create an executable application from an exe using the following method, but since it is only a backdoor method, it may cause some problems.

## Operation1

Add a WindowsPackageType tag that holds None in the PropertyGroup tag in the csproj file.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    ~omission~
    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

## Operation2

Modify the launchSettings.json file in the Properties folder in the project as follows

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Windows Machine": {
      "commandName": "Project", ←Rewrite from MsixPackage to Project
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
}
```

## References

- https://blog.verslu.is/maui/dotnet-maui-windows-unpackaged-apps/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/overview

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I knew it had to be simpler than all the UWP hacks.

Comment: @GuildOfCalamity After following these steps, copied the exe to my other machine and double clicking the generated exe is not doing anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have never run the created exe on another PC, so I will try it when I have time and report back.

Comment: @tkMaui, from your statement: "create an executable application from an exe" --> I was thinking, we should be able to run the application from exe. What do you mean by executable application here?

Comment: I have tried sending the bin folder to another pc and running the exe file but the application is running in my environment.

Did you by any chance try to move only the exe file to the other machine and run it?
If so, there are some assemblies missing.
I don't think it will even start.
project/bin/debug or release/.net6-windows[versiion num].
folder to another machine and try to run it.

If that is the only reason, I don't know.

Comment: You need the WindowsAppSDK Runtime to be installed and also the Visual C++ Redistributables. Then the unpacked exe will work. It was possible to use -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true as parameter for publish also, but does not work all the time..

Answer (score 6):

It is very simple
Just right click on project file(or double click on project file) then click on
'edit project file'. Just add the following tag within the **PropertyGroup** tag.

```
 <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
```

And change **CommandName** parameter from **MsixPackage** to **Project** in launchSetting.json file. Or just copy past the following code into launchSetting.json file.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Windows Machine": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the older, accepted answer with more upvotes does not?

Comment: I just tried to make the answer simple.