# .NET MAUI App (exe) doesnt start after building (Release or Debug)

Tags: c#, windows, maui

Why can't I run a MAUI app (for Windows) that was successfully built in Release Mode or Debug Mode.
It can be executed from Visual Studio without any problems.
Is it possible that it is only standalone executable when built via publish?
If I double click the exe file in the debug or release folder nothing happens. Also no error message. During the build process there were no errors or warnings.

Comment: Did this answer your question? [Easiest way to launch a MAUI app exe on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718305/easiest-way-to-launch-a-maui-app-exe-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

**Just enable nonpackage publishing**:

Go to Solution Explorer and click on your project to access XAML file of your project.

Inside `<PropertyGroup>` put `<WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>`, then rebuild the project.

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/GgU4ulGYQEk?t=70) how to do this, see after 01:10

Boom, You are done, now you can run your app from build folder (using .exe file) and spread this build as usual app.